# insert data to a record already saved to a table

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a recordset that is missing one field for each record and would like to add some data from a form by looking up certain criteria. I used a select query to get data onto the form in the first place and tried to reverse the assigning of values but it doesnt work as it says Run-time error 3027 'the Database or Object is Read only.' I think this is because I ran a select query to get the information but how do I input the data to the same records. the code I used is below -

```
Private Sub CmdAppend_Click()

Dim dbsNorthwind As dao.Database
Dim rstAmend As dao.Recordset
Dim qdfAmend As dao.QueryDef
Dim n As Integer

Set dbsNorthwind = CurrentDb



Set qdfAmend = dbsNorthwind.QueryDefs("Get_Questions_NTL")
qdfAmend.Parameters(0) = [Forms]![TeamLeader]![ComClientNotFin]
qdfAmend.Parameters(1) = [Forms]![TeamLeader]![ComDateSelect]
Set rstAmend = qdfAmend.OpenRecordset(dbOpenDynaset)
n = 0
   rstAmend.MoveFirst
   Do Until rstAmend.EOF
      n = n + 1
      rstAmend.Fields("ManagerID") = Form.Controls("SC" & n).Value

      rstAmend.MoveNext
   Loop


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to use the .Edit and .Update methods of the recordset object to update records. You received the error because you are trying to assign a value to a read only property.